# Consequences of caching string length in a native C++ class?

Tags: c++, string

So we have a custom string class that just wraps a basic C string: char* or a wchar_t*. The only data member of our custom string class is this pointer. Anyways, here at work we are debating adding another member that caches the length of the internal char array. So instead of

> MyString::Count { return _tcslen(foo); }

we could just write:

> MyString::Count { return m_count; }

But I'm sure there is a special gotcha that would bite us if we did that. You know, some special way to break such an implementation wide open. So my question is, what are the downsides of caching the length?

Comment: "*So we have a custom string class that just wraps a basic C string*" Ohgodwhy

Comment: what is wrong with the standard string/wstring !?

Comment: Let's just say it's old legacy code. Probably predates much of STL too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: don't do it unless you have *profiling data showing this is really a bottleneck*. If you don't have that, you've all been wasting your time arguing about this IMO. Make your code correct first, then attack the important bottlenecks.

If you do cache it, make sure all the paths that could modify the internal string also update the `m_count` appropriately.

If your wrapper hands out a non-const reference or a pointer to the data, don't cache it - you can't be certain that the value will remain fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There are no real downsides to caching the length. The std::string class does the same thing. This also allows you to store NUL characters within your data if you choose to.

Just make sure your data and the cached value are always in sync through accessors and possibly protected data members.

Comment: C++'s std::string doesn't "cache" the length. The stored length _is_ the final authority on the string's length.

Answer (score 2):

What if someone changes the string contents without calling a special "update count" function? At that point, your saved count and the string itself are out of sync, which could lead to all sorts of problems, including crashes.

Comment: So for instance if you hand out a pointer to the internal contents of the string (i.e. const char* GetData() ), and then modify the pointer outside the string class?

Comment: Exactly. Are you sure nobody does that? If not, it's something you'll need to check before you can make the optimization.

Comment: Oh I'm positive that the accessor function to get the internals is used very much...

Comment: The issue, C Johnson, is whether the accessor function is used to *modify* the internals, and then whether it's used to modify the internals such that the computed length of the string would change. If the number of `\0` characters never changes, then it's safe to cache the length.